# Htaccess redirect from example.com/en/app to example.com/app?lang=en

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to do this using htaccess but getting no success:

```
example.com/en/app
```

to

```
example.com/app?lang=en
```

And

```
example.com/en/
```

to

```
example.com/?lang=en
```

Can anyone help me here please?

In short all I need is: "en" should come always as query string parameter.

Answer (score 3):

[base on Apache document](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.*)$ http://example.com/$2?lang=$1 [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: I edited your answer, I removed the example.com from RewriteRule, because domain name is not part of match in Rule pattern.

Comment: thanks for your answer again. but its now going to too many redirections loop.

Comment: @NNCInfotechPrivateLimited I tested the rule on my server ,its working fine.

Comment: For me not really. Its redirecting me to infinite loop and also its not working if I only add example.com/en/. Its only redirecting when I use exmaple.com/en/app. please help here.

Comment: replace `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` with `RewriteCond "http://example.com/$1/$2" !-d`